# How to check whether time overlaps?

Tags: java, android, datetime, time, overlap

I have created an events. These now I want to check if they overlap each other. I have stored startTime and endTime in a date format in database.

Now I want to check if time of the events dose overlap. For this I have thought to get all the events startTime and endTime, retrieve the hours and minutes from date and then compare the hours and minutes with current hours and minutes.

Date format is this:  df = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzzz yyyy");

I first had tried to compare two dates by a query but it dose not help well. If the event is not present at that time then also sometimes it returns true.

My first attempt was this:

```
public int returnCount(String startTime, String endTime, String day)
{
    String selectQuery = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " + TABLE + " WHERE " + KEY_DAY_OF_WEEK + " = '" + day + "'" + " AND "

            + "(" + KEY_FROM_DATE + " <= '" + startTime
            + "' AND '" + startTime + "' <= " + KEY_TO_DATE + ") OR "

            + " (" + KEY_FROM_DATE + " <= '" + endTime
            + "' AND '" + endTime + "' <= " + KEY_TO_DATE + ") OR "

            + " (" + KEY_FROM_DATE + " <= '" + startTime
            + "' AND '" + endTime + "' <= " + KEY_TO_DATE + ") OR "

            + " (" + KEY_FROM_DATE + " <= '" + endTime
            + "' AND '" + startTime + "' <= " + KEY_FROM_DATE + ") OR "

            + " (" + KEY_TO_DATE + " <= '" + startTime
            + "' AND '" + endTime + "' <= " + KEY_TO_DATE + ") OR "

            + " ('" + startTime + "' < " + KEY_FROM_DATE
            + " AND " + KEY_TO_DATE + " < '" + endTime + "')";

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor mCount= db.rawQuery(selectQuery,null);

    if (mCount.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            EventData event = new EventData();
            count = mCount.getInt(0);
        } while (mCount.moveToNext());
    }

    Log.d("query",selectQuery);

    Log.d("count",String.valueOf(count));
    mCount.close();

    return count;

}
```

So now I thought to make a change and compare hours and minutes. For this my attempt was to  get hours and minutes convert it in string and then compare, but it dose not help well.

```
 public void checkOverlappingEvents()
{

    List<EventData> checkOverlappingEvents = new ArrayList<>();

    EventTableHelper eventTableHelper = new EventTableHelper(AddEventActivity.this);


    checkOverlappingEvents = eventTableHelper.getAllEvents("Mon");


    for (EventData e : checkOverlappingEvents)
    {

        df = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzzz yyyy");

        Date checkFromDate = new Date();
        Date checkToDate = new Date();


        try {

            checkFromDate = df.parse(e.getFromDate());
            checkToDate = df.parse(e.getToDate());

        } catch (ParseException ex) {

        }


        int startHours = datefrom.getHours();
        int endHours = dateto.getMinutes();

        String startTime = checkFromDate.getHours() + ":" + checkFromDate.getMinutes();
        String endTime = checkToDate.getHours() + ":" + checkToDate.getMinutes();

        String startDate = datefrom.getHours() + ":" + datefrom.getMinutes();
        String endDate = dateto.getHours() + ":" + dateto.getMinutes();

        if(startTime.equals(startDate) && endTime.equals(endDate))
        {
            overlapEvents = true;
        }

    }

}
```

getAllEvents query:

```
 public List<EventData> getAllEvents(String day) {
    List<EventData> conList = new ArrayList<EventData>();

    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE + " WHERE " + KEY_DAY_OF_WEEK + " = '" + day + "'";

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {

            EventData event = new EventData();

            event.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            event.setTitle(cursor.getString(1));
            event.setFromDate(cursor.getString(2));
            event.setToDate(cursor.getString(3));
            event.setDayOfWeek(cursor.getString(4));
            event.setLocation(cursor.getString(5));
            event.setNotificationTime(cursor.getString(6));
            event.setTableId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(7)));
            event.setNotificationId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(8)));
            event.setNotification(cursor.getString(9));



            conList.add(event);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    return conList;
}
```

EDIT:

```
public void checkOverlappingEvents()
{

    List<EventData> checkOverlappingEvents = new ArrayList<>();

    EventTableHelper eventTableHelper = new EventTableHelper(AddEventActivity.this);


    checkOverlappingEvents = eventTableHelper.getAllEvents("Mon");


    for (EventData e : checkOverlappingEvents)
    {

        df = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzzz yyyy");

        Date checkFromDate = new Date();
        Date checkToDate = new Date();


        try {

            checkFromDate = df.parse(e.getFromDate());
            checkToDate = df.parse(e.getToDate());

        } catch (ParseException ex) {

        }
```

checkToDate.getMinutes();

```
        if(datefrom.compareTo(checkToDate) == checkFromDate.compareTo(dateto))
        {
            overlapEvents = true;
        }

    }

}
```

I did this so it works well for adding a new event. Checks for the other dates if they dose overlap or not, But I want to update the event also.

If I used this same function and only change the end time of an existing event then as start time is same it always shows event exists. How can I compare while doing update for events?

Can anyone help how can I compare the hours and minutes with current hours and minutes?

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `java.util.Calendar`, and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now legacy, supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & Java 7 in the [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project. Further adapted for earlier Android in the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Answer (score 2):

I would use `Date` Objects

```
Date startDate1 = ...
Date startDate2 = ...
Date endDate1 = ...
Date endDate2 = ...

boolean overlapping = datesOverlap(startDate1, endDate1, startDate2, endDate2);

private boolean datesOverlap(Date startDate1, endDate1, startDate2, endDate2){
    return startDate1.before(endDate2) && startDate2.before(endDate1);
}
```

Comment: what is the difference between compare to and before?@Joe Maher

Comment: @user5881997 compare compares them, returns -1 (before), 0 (same time) or 1 (after), and before obviously checks if it is before and before is all we need in this situation

Comment: ok that's nice information. Can you please check my edited question and help me for the same? @Joe Maher

Comment: I tried with compare to and also with before but events dose overlaps sometimes.@Joe Maher

Comment: Also if event is not present at a particular time then also it shows true that event exists. @Joe Maher

Comment: Looks like this won't cover the case where one event is within the other. I think you want to test the opposite case: if (startDate1.after(endDate2) || startDate2.after(endDate1)) then the events do NOT overlap.

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you convert your strings `startTime` and `endTime` to `Date` objects, and use `date1.compareTo(date2)`, which returns `1` if `date2` occurs after, `-1` if before, `0` same time. So you would have something like that:

```
if(start1.compareTo(start2) != end1.compareTo(start2)) /*overlaps*/;
```

You can see how that works when you visualize it:

```
start1--------start2------end1--------end2  → will return true
start1--------end1------start2--------end2  → will return false
```

**Note** that this counts cases where a range starts exactly when the other stops as overlapping. If you want otherwise, you should handle cases where a start is the same as the other end

Comment: Will this check for all overlapping times?

Comment: now I have a event on 7 pm to 8 pm now I tried to add another event on 6 pm to 6 :30 pm. there is no event at this time still it returns true. If i tried this way

Comment: Source for that attempt? Because you are much better off using Date objects than trying to calculate it yourself

Comment: @user5881997 oops sorry I made a typo, I corrected it. I had `s1.compareTo(e2) != e1.compareTo(s2)` when I meant `s1.compareTo(s2) != e1.compareTo(s2)`

Comment: no I think it was right ,, i tried first         if(checkFromDate.compareTo(datefrom) == checkToDate.compareTo(dateto)) this then I again checked your ans and corrected to :    if(datefrom.compareTo(checkToDate) == checkFromDate.compareTo(dateto)) ,,,,,,, I think works fine,, let me test for all conditions